# Representing Objective C Protocols on UML class diagrams

Tags: objective-c, uml, protocols, class-diagram

How should I correctly reference protocols on a UML class diagram?

For example my `ListViewController` conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols... where do I put the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `numberOfRowsInSection` methods? ... in `ListViewController` where they are implemented or in something like this:

```
         <<Protocol>>
    UITableViewDataSource 
    ---------------------

    ---------------------
    -numberOfRowsInSection
```

If I did the latter what would be the association between the `ListViewController` class and the protocol box be? All I have to show is how I hook into Cocoa Touch some how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Protocols are sort of equivalent to interfaces in java, so you can find a java UML diagram and work off that.

Also, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram:

> In UML modeling, a realization
>   relationship is a relationship between
>   two model elements, in which one model
>   element (the client) realizes the
>   behavior that the other model element
>   (the supplier) specifies. A
>   realization is indicated by **a dashed
>   line with an unfilled arrowhead
>   towards the supplier**.
>
> ...
>
> A realization relationship between
>   classes and interfaces and between
>   components and interfaces shows that
>   the class realizes the operations
>   offered by the interface.

So if I'm reading that correctly, `ListViewController` would have a dashed line with an unfilled arrowhead pointing to `UITableViewDataSource`.